# How to read unicode data from xlsx using PHPExcel?

Tags: php, unicode, phpexcel, spreadsheet, xlsx

Normal `ASCII` data is reading fine with this code in `xlsx`!

```
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
  $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A'.$row.':'.$highestColumn.$row,NULL,TRUE,TRUE);
}
```

But not able to read *unicode* data with this.
Is there any way to read *unicode* with this from xlsx?

**Note :** *unicode* working fine with xls! i am not getting it from xlsx only!

Comment: What Unicode character(s) are in the ``xslx`` file and what shows up instead of them?

Comment: this is the unicode !  "സ്വാഗതം" ! and null value is showing instead of this!

Comment: could you provide a minimal working example (meaning: the script that works on its own + xlsx file), I find the amount of data you provide .... lacking.